# How do I create a download link from data in memory?

Tags: 8

I need to create a Controller that serves data as a download when accessed. That file is not in the file system but in memory; that's why I need a Controller instead of just serve file.

How do I create a download link from data in memory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My approach is to use a Symfony Response obejct as explained here: The [HttpFoundation Component: Serving files](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#serving-files).

Firts setup the routing:

```
mymodule.download_item:
  path: '/myitems/{item_id}/download'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyController::downloadItem'
```

So the controller looks like:

```
class MyController extends ControllerBase {
 public function downloadItem($item_id) {

    $fileContent = functionToObtainExternalContent($item_id);
    $response = new Response($fileContent);

    $disposition = $response->headers->makeDisposition(
        ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, 'foo.txt'
    );

    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $disposition);

    return $response;
  }
}
```